# whenever I open gitbash I get the error "bash: /c/Users/aditya royal/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory"

Tags: terminal, git-bash

The exact error is:

```
bash: /c/Users/aditya royal/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
```

What does this command mean and how to get rid of this?

Comment: You mean an *error*...

Answer (score 2):

Check your `/c/Users/aditya royal/.bashrc`

It should include a `. ~/git-prompt.sh` line.

Check if deleting this line would allow you to avoid the error message.

See more at "[Git in Other Environments - Git in Bash](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash)"

The comments in [`git/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) explain what this file is for, and how it should be properly activated.